# In 2.81, particles aren't rendering with their materials (object mode in cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, particles

I'm trying to render some cool wallpaper for a new phone I'll be getting in a few weeks.  I have an object generating particles that are falling from it.  These particles are rendered in "Object" mode based from another object.  In Eevee and Cycles, the particles render (and look pretty good) but don't use the material I've created.  In workbench, I can get really good looking renders, however I can't use a material with nodes, which I need because I'm trying to achieve a metallic look.  I'm new to 2.81 (coming from 2.79) so there may be an obvious solution to this that I can't find because of the way a lot of menus got rearranged.  Thanks in advance for your help!
[image]

This image is a render using Cycles.  The objects/particles look great, but the material aren't being used.
There is also a screenshot of my blender window.  If there are particular settings that you need to know about, let me know in the comments and I will provide that info too.
[image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Could you include screenshots? It is difficult to discern your setup from text alone.

Comment: I added a few screenshots.  If there are any additional settings that weren't on screen that you need to see, let me know and I'll take care of it.

Comment: Could you show the Particle Emitter settings? If there's an issue, that's where the issue would most likely be. You can also upload the blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded the .blend file.  At the moment, it is rendering using the material now, however, I have no idea what I did that made it do so.  At this point, if there's no obvious "Here's the setting you should check if it happens again" kind of solution, it's okay to just drop the question as it seems to have fixed itself.